# Symfony3 doctrine orm find method

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am writing a Symfony3 appusing Doctrine ORM.

SO what i am trying to do is to find if a given email address exists in a table (every email is unique). so i have a user repository with some attributes I can easily persist data to the db but failing to retrive data.

```
/**
 * @param $email
 */
public function findUserByEmail($email)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TestBundle:TestUser')
        ->find($email);

    if (!$user) {
        echo 'Error';die();
    }
}
```

I know the var passed to the function contains a email string, but what i get in return is error and when i var_dump $user before the if statment i get null.

I followed the Symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your `User` probably has a separate primary key field. the `find()` method on a repo only retrieves by primary key.

[Repositories use `__call` to dynamically process `findBy*` and `findOneBy*` methods](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions), so you could call it like this:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:TestUser');

// magic find method
$user = $repo->findOneByEmail($email);

// explicit find method
$user = $repo->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

// custom QueryBuilder
$user = $repo->createQueryBuilder('user')
    ->where('user.email = :email')
    ->setParameter('email', $email)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

BTW: If you are validating this for a submitted form, there is a contraint that does this check for you: [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Comment: Ok it might be the case because ID is the primary key, but findOneByEmail is not a valid getDoctrine method...?

Comment: the actual method does not exist, but doctrine catches it through the [magic `__call` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) on the Entity's Repository and converts it to select by email.

Comment: I will give this a try now, but just have a feeling there must be a simpler solution for this something out of a Doctrinebox

Comment: Further documentation & alternatives: http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#querying

Comment: @Tomazi, this is out of the doctrine box, it's a feature of the a Doctrine Repository.

Comment: As the documentation states, it's just a matter using the property of the entity in the function name, [the `__call` function is what handles this in the base `EntityRepository` class](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L199)

Comment: Perfect answer. Possibly worth noting the alternative syntax also; i.e: `$repo->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);` which allows for multiple filter criteria, and accepts an array as a second argument in order to specify ordering criteria.

Comment: I've added the regular `findBy` method, and an example of using a custom `QueryBuilder` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you forgot to call `getManager()`.

So the code would be:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:TestUser')->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
```

Hope it would help you!